# PHP - How to create 4 columns (4 x 25%) and then end the line with a new column of 4

Tags: php, html, css

I have a project going on where we are able to create a product, which is loaded to the front page in PHP.
However, if there are 5 products, then it won't create a new line. What should happen if there are 5 products is 2 lines of 4 each should be displayed.

```
<section class="ICO">
    <div class="one-fourth-gridtable">
        <table class="grid table">
            <?php
            while ($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subject_set)) {
                $imagenavn = $subject['navn'];
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM product_images WHERE image_name = '$imagenavn'";
                $sth = $db->query($sql);
                $result = mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
                ?>
                <td>
                    <div style="border: 1px solid black; border-radius:2000px;">
                        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?= base64_encode($result['image']); ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <a class="action" href="<?= url_for('../show.php?id=' . h(u($subject['id']))); ?>"><?php echo h($subject['navn']); ?></a>
                </td>      
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</section>
```

I tried to style the table with CSS:

```
table {
    background-color: #6991ac;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-table;
    margin-top: -5%;
}
.ICO {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.one-fourth-gridtable {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The structure you're trying to achieve could probably be better done using generic `div`s, a table will fit in as many cells, or columns, in a row that it can so long as you keep adding `td` elements to a `tr` element.

Comment: "_How to create 4 columns (4 x 25%) and then end the line with a new column of 4_"... does that mean you want 4 columns of table cells and starting with the 5th, move to subsequent rows? Can you update your question to include sample output (e.g. HTML, a graphic)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code you get a new line after 4 images and after 8 images the loops stops because of the $u. You can delete/change the $u if not needed.

```html
<?php require_once('private/initialize.php'); ?>
<?php $test = "Alle Produkter"; ?>
<?php $subject_set = find_all_subjects(); ?>
<?php $page_title = 'Forside'; ?>
<?php include(SHARED_PATH . '/staff_header.php'); ?>

<!--- Start of header --><head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="design/Design.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<!--- End of header -->

<!--- Start of section (BANNER) -->



<section class="banner">
 <div class="banner-inner">
     <div id="banner-image"><img src="img/cryptocurrency.png" style="margin-top:10% !important"></div>
    </div>
</section>

<!--- End of section (BANNER) -->

<!--- Start of section (ICO'S) -->



<!--- End of section (ICO'S) -->


      <div class="sactions">
      <!-- <a class="saction" href="<?php echo url_for('/staff/subjects/new.php'); ?>">Create New Subject</a> -->         </div>


<section class="ICO">
  <div class="one-fourth-gridtable">
      <table class="gridtable">

    <?php
$i = 0;
$u = 0;
    while($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subject_set)) {
      $imagenavn = $subject['navn'];
              $sql = "SELECT * FROM product_images WHERE image_name = '$imagenavn'";
              $sth = $db->query($sql);
              $result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);

$i++;
$u ++;
    ?>



    <td>




            <?php


      echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).  '"/> ';  ?>
      <a class="action" href="<?php echo url_for('../show.php?id=' . h(u($subject['id']))); ?>"><?php echo h($subject['navn']);?></a>
<?php
if ($u > 7 ) {
 break;

}
if ($i > 3) {
 echo '</tr><tr>';
 $i = 0;
}

 ?>



             </td>




        <?php } ?>


     </table>

            </div>
            </section>

      <?php
         mysqli_free_result($subject_set);
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tables automatically expand to contain all of the elements on a single row.

To get around this, you **could** simply make use of new table rows (`<tr>`), though I would recommend swapping to a `<div>` layout and `float`ing the elements to the `left`:

```
<div class="contents">
 // output the contents
</div>

.contents img {
  float: left;
}
```

This will cause the elements to automatically move to the next line when occupying more than the available width, with no need to worry about how many elements should be displayed per row:

```css
.contents img {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contents">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

First count the results to display, say $count.

```
<table class="grid table">
<tr>
<?php 
$trer = 1;
$cycler = 0;
while($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subject_set))
{
     $cycler++;
                 $imagenavn = $subject['navn'];
                 $sql = "SELECT * FROM product_images WHERE image_name = '$imagenavn'";
                 $sth = $db->query($sql);
                 $result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
 ?>

            <td>YOUR CONTENT</td>
<?php
if($trer == 4 && $cycler < $count) //if true you're at the last td of the line, but not on the last line, so let's put a new line
  {
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    $trer = 0;
  }
$trer++;
}
if($trer > 0 && $trer < 4) //if line is incomplete (less than 4 items but 1 or more
{
  for(int t = 0; $t < 4 - $trer; $t++) //echo empty TDs till filling the line
     echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```